# Inserting image inside SVG blob

Tags: html, image, blob

What I am trying to achieve is to place image inside the SVG blob. The problem is that the image is not inside the blob but 'sticks out' over the blob's borders. My goal is to not show the image outside the blob. Any help would be very appreciated.

```html
  <svg id="visual" viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
               <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" fill="#fff">                 
               </rect>
               <g transform="translate(292.7 145.85)">
                 <path id="svg1" d="M189.3 52.1C189.3 166.7 94.7 333.3 -21.3 333.3C-137.3 333.3 -274.7 166.7 -274.7 52.1C-274.7 -62.5 -137.3 -125 -21.3 -125C94.7 -125 189.3 
                 -62.5 189.3 52.1" fill="#2590eb">
                  </path>
                  
                </g><image  xlink:href="https://www.pngplay.com/wp-content/uploads/7/Happy-Person-Transparent-Background.png" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" clip-path="url(#svg1)" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"/>
              </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `<clipPath>`

Is something like this you are looking for?

Here is a snippet example you could apply to your code

```css
body {
  background: #EDE29F;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">

   <clipPath id="clip-path">
 <path d="M22.154,108.389 L258.274,13.5 L449.156,151.421 L487.774,429.469 L211.933,472.5 L30.981,366.577 L22.154,108.389 z">
   </clipPath>
<!-- xlink:href for modern browsers, src for IE8- -->
<image clip-path="url(#clip-path)" xlink:href="https://www.vzhurudolu.cz/assets/codepen/kubik_ig.jpg"  src="https://www.vzhurudolu.cz/assets/codepen/kubik_ig.jpg" alt="Image" height="500" width="500" class="svg__image">       
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I was looking for. Im new in SVG and I seen that in some cases there is ```clippath``` and sometimes there isn't. Could you apply this to my blob shape? Thank you

Comment: If I apply my ```d=....``` to Your code I get weird results.